# Raw sausage left at doorstep for 4 hours

Tags: food-safety

So guidelines say 2 hours unrefrigerated for raw sausage and raw meatballs... but I was wondering if it's still ok at 4 hours if it passes the smell test.

I had a grocery delivery during the day where they didn't ring the doorbell and I only discovered it at 5pm.  It was left in the shade but is the first hot day of the season.  It was still luke cool to the touch but definitely not cold.  The ice cream bars had melted and become runny.

I was going to cook all the bratwurst and meatballs the next day if it would be ok.  Otherwise, I'd have to throw them out.

Should I eat or throw away?

Comment: Sorry, but more that “safe or unsafe” is impossible to say. The point is that you need to differentiate between “safe or unsafe” and “actually spoiled” - they are not the same thing. It’s up to you whether you want to take the risk of eating food that isn’t safe or not.

Comment: If it were me I would cook the sausage and not worry about it.  Bacteria will grow in 1, 2, or 4 hours, but assuming it was handled properly before it got to your door (i.e. it hadn't already been sitting for hours) the difference between 2 and 4 hours is negligible. If you cook the sausage past 180F (which I normally do anyway) you should be fine. I prefer bratwurst "well done" so that a lot of the fat has rendered and the skin is crispy.

Comment: Smell is an unreliable test of food safety.